# What exercises would help recover from thoracic spinal trauma?

Tags: weightlifting, spine

Had surgery and radiation 3 years ago on a tumor inside my spinal cord in my thoracic spine. This causes weakness, numbness and uncontrolled movement in my left leg to the point where people often comment on it, but I can live a relatively normal life.  Still young (23), and would prefer rigorous exercise involving progressive overload to help recover. I have a gym membership, so I have access to standard gym equipment. What exercises can I do to help recover from this?

ps. I've different forms of exercise with varying degrees of success, but nothing worked 100%.

Comment: Can you squat to proper depth without any pain?

Comment: I can, but my knees are wobbly

Comment: If you're still trying to recover, wouldn't it make more sense to work with a physical therapist?

Comment: I agree ask someone who is knowledgeable in physical therapy. If he gives you a thumbs up, you should probably just focus on doing some of the full body movements like squats.

Comment: I would but I don't have money for it

Comment: Given your recent medical history, I would advise against accepting instruction from anyone here since they do not know your limitations and are not privy to your medical history, diagnosis, and outcome.

Comment: @user4757074, putting your comments together, it sounds as though you've tried squatting and progressive overload, and had varying (but not 100%) success. What are you looking for?  Why not, for example, continue training your squats with progressive overload, and thereby strengthen your legs, etc.?

Comment: Well, I've tried this but it usually gets to a point (usually happens at 250 1rm) where I can't add weight without form breaking down even if I train at that weight for a while, ramp up the reps at that weight.... It also would get to the point where I wouldn't get a good workout because I couldn't add any more weight. Recently I tried doing 10*10 with 135 and that seems to work as far as getting a workout. Recently (this week and last week), I've been following this video: https://vimeo.com/11702014 and it seems to work, but 2 weeks isn't really long enough to say.